# Using Visual Studio to replaces default.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-designer, deployment, visual-studio

I want to replace the default.aspx with my own.  The problem i am running into is strange.
I created a module with default.aspx in it.  I copy and pasted the following into the main Content

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="Left" Title="loc:Left"><ZoneTemplate>
            <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" Description="Use this list to track upcoming events, status updates or other team news." ListDisplayName="" PartOrder="2" HelpLink="" AllowRemove="True" IsVisible="True" AllowHide="True" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" ExportControlledProperties="False" IsIncludedFilter="" DataSourceID="" Title="Announcements" ViewFlag="8388621" NoDefaultStyle="" AllowConnect="True" FrameState="Normal" PageSize="-1" PartImageLarge="" AsyncRefresh="False" Dir="Default" DetailLink="/Lists/Announcements" ShowWithSampleData="False" ListId="0b45f366-d973-452f-9eac-f222c59aa896" ListName="{0B45F366-D973-452F-9EAC-F222C59AA896}" FrameType="Default" PartImageSmall="" IsIncluded="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" AllowEdit="True" ViewGuid="{101B74E6-7B7C-47ED-9448-24AC2EE03E3A}" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" AllowMinimize="True" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ViewContentTypeId="0x" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." HelpMode="Modeless" ListUrl="" ID="g_101b74e6_7b7c_47ed_9448_24ac2ee03e3a" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" AllowZoneChange="True" TitleUrl="/Lists/Announcements" ManualRefresh="False" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{101B74E6-7B7C-47ED-9448-24AC2EE03E3A}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" __designer:CustomXsl="fldtypes_Ratings.xsl" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><ParameterBindings>

             .........etc.......  </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

I then deploy it but the contents of the ZoneTemplate are missing when i go in and look at it with designer.

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="Left" Title="loc:Left"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

What am i doing wrong/Whats going on?  Here is the Elements.xml for the module that is deploying it in case you need it

```
<Module Name="Pages"><File Path="Pages\default.aspx" Url="default.aspx"  IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="False"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Didn't realize that deployment of the webpart in default.aspx had to be done through the element.xml of the module.

This needed to be within the file element

```
      <View List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,announce_Folder;" BaseViewID="0" WebPartZoneID="Left" />
```